# IronPython cannot import Data Entity (System.Data.Entity)

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ironpython

Here is the code I used:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("System.Data")
clr.AddReference("System.Data.Entity")
from System.Data.Entity import DbSet
```

I got this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 1, in 
>   ImportError: No module named Entity

I am confused. If there were really no such module named `Entity`, I should fail when I add `System.Data.Entity` as reference.

Why this happened? Do I need to set connection string before importing?

Thanks

Comment: What is the output of `[assembly.GetName().Name for assembly in clr.References]` if run before you attempt to import `DbSet`?  It sounds like its not finding the reference.

Comment: ['mscorlib', 'System', 'IronPython.SQLite', 'IronPython.Wpf', 'System.Data', 'System.Data.Entity']